# How to find groups of players often playing together

Tags: mysql, sql, algorithm, grouping, complexity-theory

I'm quite stuck by an algorithm and I would like some help.

I've a video game for which I have a lot of `Tuple<MatchId,PlayerId>` (~100Million). All those tuples are in a Mysql database but can be exported to a text file if needed.

In this game, all the matches have 9 players. I want to find the groups of players who often play together, that is to say who played at least 10 matches together, and I want this number of matches.

Currently my solution is the following : 
I first group those tuples to have `Tuple<MatchId, Collection<PlayerId>>`
So, the collection has between 1 and 9 players.

Then, for `subgroupSize` between 2 and 9 : 
For each line of the list, I generate all the subgroups with a size of `subgroupSize` (`maximum=126` for `subgroupSize=5`).

I then create another list `Tuple<MatchId, Subgroup>`. I then group this second list by subgroup, I then filter and I get the result for this `subgroupSize`.

The problem is that, for `subgroupSize`=5, I will have my second list which will have a size of 126 times the first one, which is rougly 1 billion lines before the filtering...

So, I wanted to know if you have a better solution to propose :)

Thanks guys, have a nice day !

Comment: Create a graph structure with edge weights as number of games played together. Then iterate the entire graph and remove all edges with weight lower then needed. You can use graph nosql database, jak neo4j. It would allow you perform queries like the one you've described easily using cypher query language.

Comment: How many players do you have?

Comment: Do You consider at least a couple as a group or all 9 players have to be same?

Comment: You don't need to invent anything. This is a very common problem in the Data Mining field referred to as "frequent items" for example. You can find plenty of algorithms on the internet.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method that you can implement in MySQL.  The idea is to take an iterative approach.  Build a table of 2-player combos, then 3-player combos and so on.  Keep the intermediate tables and index them appropriately.

First, create a list of players that have played in at least 10 matches:

```
create table players1 as
    select t1.playerid
    from tuples t1
    group by t1.playerid
    having count(*) >= 10;
```

For pairs of players:

```
create table players2 as
    select t1.playerid as playerid1, t2.playerid as playerid2
    from players1 p1 join
         tuples t1
         on p1.playerid = t1.playerid join
         tuples t2
         on t1.matchid = t2.matchid and
            t1.playerid < t2.playerid join
         players1 p2
         on t2.playersid = p2.playersid
    group by t1.playerid, t2.playerid
    having count(*) >= 10;
```

The idea here is that the `players1` table is being used as a filter for the `tuples` table.

You can then repeat this process for subsequent tables.

To be honest, I'm not sure how efficient this will be in MySQL.  It depends a lot on the number of players and the number of players who have played 10 or more matches.

Answer (score 0):

A query like this should get you started.

```
select field1, field2, etc, count(*) matches
from yourtable t1 join yourtable t2 on t1.MatchId = t2.MatchId
and t1.PlayerId <> t2.PlayerId
where whatever
group by field1, field2, etc
having count(*) > 10
```

You just have to decide what fields you want.  You also have to join to the Player table twice to get the names of the players.